# skipping waiting time on setTimeout

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I have a video with many buttons,each button makes video forwarding to a specific point , after waiting 5 seconds.

```
function setTimeVid(button) {
            if(button.id=='b1'){
                timerId=setTimeout(function(){
                    vid.currentTime=point1;
                },5000);
            }
            if(button.id=='b2'){
                timerId=setTimeout(function(){
                    vid.currentTime=point2;
                },5000); 
            }
// and 5-6 more
```

Last button, where `button.id` is equal to `"skipping"`, should be canceling the 5 seconds waiting time,and running the function immediately.

Assume that "skipping" button can be pressed only when `setTimeout` already started. I need it to skip waiting 5 seconds and running it immediately. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Not certain what Question is? Do you call `clearTimeout(timerId)` within `javascript`?

Comment: No clearTimeout,this will just cancel the function,i need it to skip waiting 5 seconds and running it immediately

Comment: Note that you are setting and overwriting `timerId` at each call to `setTimeVid`.

Comment: @ArkadisStepanov, on which button b1 or b2?

Comment: @guest271314 the first method works perfectly,but have to write many if statements to get the specific point

Comment: @ArkadisStepanov How is `setVidTime` called? Can you include `html`, full `javascript` at Question?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the `clearTimeout` method

```js
let timeoutReference;

const startButton = document.getElementById('start');
const skipButton = document.getElementById('skip');

const yourFunction = () => {
  const text = document.createElement('div');
  text.innerHTML = 'sarasa';
  document.body.appendChild(text);
  skipButton.disabled = true;
}

const waitTime = () => {
  timeoutReference = setTimeout(yourFunction, 2000);
}

startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  skipButton.disabled = false;
  waitTime();
});

skipButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  clearTimeout(timeoutReference);
  yourFunction();
});
```

```html
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="skip" disabled>Skip</button>
```

Comment: You can simplify to `setTimeout(yourFunction, 2000)`; `toggleDisable` is never used; and in the skipbutton you don't need to disable the button explicitly after calling `yourFunction()`

Comment: @Arkadis Stepanov is it what you are looking for?